# .Net Core "Http failure response 404 Not Found" error

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am just starting to get into netcore 2.2 and I am trying to call my controller from angular as so however  when I call the send contact email method from my service I get a "Http failure response for http://localhost:53270/api/DataController/SendContactEmail/: 404 Not Found"

As you can clearly see I am explicitly writing out the route in the below routine

```
 sendContactEmail(contact: ISubmitModel): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.post<any>('api/DataController/SendContactEmail/', contact)      
    }
```

and my controller method

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DataController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SendContactEmail(ContactUs contact)
    {
        ContactUs form = new ContactUs()
        {
            Email = contact.Email,
            Name = contact.Name,
            Phone = contact.Phone,
            Message = contact.Message
        };

        return Ok(form);
    }

    public class ContactUs
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Your route to api should be `'api/Data/SendContactEmail'`

Comment: As @penleychan mention, you don't need the "Controller" word after Data, when MVC generate the route it only use the controller name wich is Data not DataController

Comment: @penleychan so I tried that and now get this error "POST http://localhost:51889/api/Data/SendContactEmail 404 (Not Found)"  Is there something else that I need to do? Do I need to register this controller?

Comment: @TerranceJackson are you sure the url is correct with the port?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes I am using the url given to me from the dotnet run command. But when I run straight IIS only from vs2019 it works using the Postman application. It just doesn't run with my angular 8 and the dot net run command

Comment: The URL on the angular service should be absolute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ommit the **`Controller`** part and just use Data

```
return this._http.post<any>('http://localhost:51889/api/Data/SendContactEmail/', contact)
```

Comment: I tried this and it still gives error. After further testing running iis express from vs2019 along with PostMan this link works http://localhost:9220/api/Data/SendContactEmail however when I run the app from "dotnet run" and use the localhost link from there it doesn't work. So something is happening from dotnet run and just running iis from vs2019

Comment: you need to add the http

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned you should not be using the word **Controller** in the route since you're using the Route Attribute with the template [controller] inside the route it'll only take the name of that controller without including the Controller word.

To make it more readable you could change the template api/[controller] for api/data so it doesn't lead to confusion. 
This tends to be a *good practice*, because
if someday in the future you'd decide to change the name of the Controller for some reason, and you've tied the route to the controller name, the consuming applications of the api would break because the route would have changed (you don't want that) and obviously the consuming applications would have to change all the references to that route in order to work properly.